# Django - substracting time

Tags: django, sqlite

Welcome I have a problem. What field should be in model to substract times. I mean for example: 1st car made 500h 28 mins, 2nd car made 350h 15 min and i need a column substract where I'll have substraction from this two times. I made currently working model but only on integer field. When i tried time field and add something like 500:28 it gave me an error " incorrect time".

Current model:

```
class Aircraft (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    registration = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    #hours to maintenance
    hours_to_maintenance = models.IntegerField(help_text = "test", null = True)
    #current hours
    ch = models.IntegerField(help_text = "test", null = True)

    #rm = models.IntegerField(help_text = "test", null = True)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete = models.CASCADE,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.registration
```

Really thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Django has a field type designated for this type of data: DurationField. See the docs: [Django DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#durationfield)

Answer (score 0):

You’re definitely going to want to use a models.DateTimeField(...). This object is a python Date object. Here’s the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html.

Make sure you click on the DateTime objects in the left nav panel

[image: this is basically what you want]

It’s really important you read the documentation because this will layout in more detail stack exchange can provide on this solution.

If you want to know how many minutes are between two DateTime values, you’ll have to calculate it using the min, hr, day etc attributes.

Comment: ok, but if i use datetime i can't fill in django time like 500:20:00 because time there is 24h maximum